# iOS: make pen drawing like Bamboo application

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios4, drawing, opengl-es-2.0

I am making an ipad application, using GLPaint from Apple source code. I have done the drawing but I don't like my pen effect. I would like to do it as the same with Bamboo application (free) on Apple Store. I wonder to make this pen style, I need texture and algorithm to make the pen width based on the speed of drawing.

Do you have any ideas and samples for me to look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link and download source code from [here](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024)

And set width what you want on touches moved method on line setLineWidth,

Currently there is 5.

Comment: Thank you but I did the drawing already. The problem I have is I try to make the pen like pen texture in Bamboo ipad application. Their pen style is like pen writing. Thank for your effort.